# Switching from eevee to cycles messes up lighting completely

Tags: cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine, lighting, error

This is how my render preview looks in eevee:
[image: eevee]

However, if I switch to cycles, this happens:
[image: cycles]

I've been following a tutorial to get to this point, and I'm really a beginner, any of you have an idea of why this is happening? Am I forced to render it with eevee?

Comment: Lighting has much more of an effect in Cycles (especially world (environment) lighting). If you are planning on switching back and forth between render engines, know that you will often need to make modifications to your scene in order to make one look "equivalent" to the other.

Comment: @ChristopherBennett The thing is, even if I turn off all the light, the scene light doesn't change that much. Change world color doesnt affect the scene that much either, how do I get a darker scene?

Comment: You need to turn down the backgrounds strength if you want to make it dark

Answer (score 1):

I just need to uncheck "ambient occlusion".

It was making everything way too bright, even with low values.

Comment: You don't need ambient occlusion in cycles.

Comment: Read: [enable ambient occlusion in cycles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/149871/enable-ambient-occlusion-ao-in-cycles) and [how to imitate ambien occlusion in cycles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/120792/how-to-imitate-ambient-occlusion-in-cycles) and [what is 
 the purpose of ambient occlusion node inc cycles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14198/whats-the-purpose-of-ambient-occlusion-node-in-cycles)

Answer (score 0):

If you started to make a scene, and always used eevee to do your renders, it will probably look like that. There are meny differences with Eevee and Cycles.

I think making the background a little darker might work, and you might have to tweak some settings to make it look right. Eevee isn't bad, I think your render looks just fine in Eevee!